# Perpendicular lines in a hexagon should not intersect

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> The diameter of the circle circumscribed about a regular hexagon is 35
> cm. Inside each side of the hexagon we have chosen one point through
> which we draw a perpendicular line of length 20 cm inside the hexagon. Is
> it possible that none of the six drawn perpendiculars will intersect with any
> other perpendiculars?

I have found that the length of each side is 17.5 cm. If we were to draw a perpendicular from each of the two adjacent angles of the hexagon, the intersection would give us a right-angled triangle with angles of 30 and 60 degrees (where one leg is 17.5 and the hypotenuse=17.5/sin60=20.2, so that is slightly longer than the length of the perpendicular). But I need to choose exactly the interior point on the side, it's harder to prove that so far.

An explicit construction of these perpendicular lines is needed for a rigorous proof.

Comment: You are saying that each line that is added is perpendicular to the side of the hexagon that it touches?  What do you mean by “drawing one perpendicular from each of the two adjacent angles”?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/5Yo60B0) - hope this picture can help)

Comment: I don't understand. $20.2-20=0.2$ is *huge* in the sense that there are infinitely many points close to the vertex from which perpendiculars can be drawn without intersecting. Just move by any, very small distance $\varepsilon << 1$, inwards from each of the vertices.

Comment: @MyMolecules, I think that the proof in this case should be more rigorous-as I think, we need to be sure that moving these perpendicular lines from the angles to the sides will not lead to intersection at some point. As I think, at this point we are only making a hypo that they won't intersect. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @Greg okay.  Now I understand

Comment: @Greg You're right, this needs to be shown. I think you should ask for explicit construction of such six perpendiculars (and add `geometric-construction` tag).

Comment: $20\sin(60)\approx 17.32$ so you have to be within about $17.5-17.32=0.18$ distance of the vertex.

Comment: @Greg if you start with the lines touching the centers of the sides of the hexagon, you’re done. You can see they intersect.  But then one can calculate how far they can be moved from the vertexes (if they’re moved the same distance) before they intersect.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I got a different answer.  According to my results, you can move the lines over 4 cm from the verteces before they intersect.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw You are correct that my answer is too small, as I keep one arm at a vertex and see that the other has 0.18 cm of room to move about without intersecting. If you move all the arms simultaneously, then you have more room. The original question can be answered without working that out exactly. I should not have said "have to be" i.e. necessary, but merely that it is sufficient to be within that distance.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis oh I see.  Thanks for sharing.  I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  JUST REALIZED $2k\neq{m+h}$, but $k\sqrt{3}=m+h$, so $$2.5\sqrt{3}=0.5r-h$$resulting in $$2.5cm\sqrt{3}=0.5(17.5cm)-h$$so $$h=\left(8.75-2.5\sqrt{3}\right)cm\approx 4.42cm$$ THE VALUE FOR $h$ ON THE STICKY NOTE IS WRONG.

The distance each line can be translated along its respective perpendicular side of the hexagon from its respective vertex (assuming they are moved the same distance) before they intersect is $h$, shown on the sticky notes.[image]

Comment: So they do intersect.